# -bash: torch: command not found

Tags: torch

I installed torch and took care of the path.
When I type `th`, torch starts.

However when I try to run lua file,

```
$ torch data.lua
-bash: torch: command not found
```

How to install torch command? My ultimate goal is run that lua file.

Comment: I assume you followed the instructions in the [documentation](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html)? I don't see a usage that involves spelling out `torch` as a command. It all uses `th`, *e.g.*, `th file.lua`.

Comment: @lurker  Thanks for the comment. Maybe then it's author's typo. I'm following this https://github.com/wojciechz/learning_to_execute repository

Comment: Could be. The doc I found indicates that `torch` is a command once you're in the "th environment" (you have the `th>` prompt).